# Multiple Project Folders Opened in Adobe-Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

Is there a way to open multiple project folders in the side bar of Adobe-Brackets? I've tried Googling but haven't found any answer specific to this question. When I try to open a secondary project folder, the side bar will close the current project folder open and replace it with the newly opened one.

Answer (score 3):

I have exactly the same problem. Was trying to google it, but haven't found anything.

So the only way I found to be able to open multiple projects in one window is to make one Folder and than put all project you are working in that Folder. Than you will be able to open different files from different projects in the same window.

Not sure how it will work with really huge projects, but for me (I'm student) this works.

Comment: Hey that's a great work-around solution Mara, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't manage to open two folders but I just opened another brackets window and used split screen